# How to set activity to the fragment in ApplicationTestCase - NoSuchFieldException: mActivity in SupportLibrary v4-23.0.0

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, android-support-library

With update of Support library v4 to 23.0.0 version from 22.2.0, `mActivity` field has gone in Fragment.java class. From what I see, it seems to be replaced by `mHost` that has type `FragmentHostCallback`(abstract, the implementation is `HostCallbacks`, that is nested in `FragmentActivity`)

I'm heavily testing all my fragments with unit tests. Before, I created new Activity in the constructor of the test class (which extends `AbstractApplicationTest`), did some tweaks (like attaching context, etc.). And then via reflection set this new Activity as an activity for the fragment I want to test:

```
protected void setFragmentActivity(final Fragment fragment) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    final Field field = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mActivity");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(fragment, activity);
}
```

Now, the `mActivity` is no longer exist.

Why is it important: when my fragment, which I'm testing, calls `getActivity()` without this setting, I'm getting null, as fragment really has no activity.

Any ideas how can it be workarounded?
Have a brilliant day,
Konstantin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.
In short, it's wrong to go with reflection and I stick to use ActivityUnitTestCase instead.

Please find full write-up about it here:
[Unit Test an Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199000/unit-test-an-android-fragment/32295976#32295976)